# UICollectionView reload some sections crash

Tags: ios, objective-c

I reload secion when the request data is success .The method is :

`[self.collectionView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1]];`

or

```
  NSIndexPath *idx = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:1];
  [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:@[idx]];
```

And This is console output :

```
[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.30.14/UICollectionView.m:4324
```

This question is  occur occasionally!

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you post the crash log?

Comment: Put your code inside https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618045-performbatchupdates

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It happens when other sections items count are changed, but you reload just one of the changed section.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your data might be changing variably

please use

```
[self.collectionView reloadData]
```

Comment: My collection's each section have different data ,and last section can load more. however reloadData  performance is lower than reloadSections

Comment: your data might be asymmetrical for reloading that section only so I recommend reload whole collectionView